# Linked server not showing on database list

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I was hoping someone could help me understand this.

When I log into SQL server I connect to server name "orange" after that I've primarily been working in the following:

```
select *
from openquery (lemon,'
...
...
with ur')
```

I guess what I want to know is all the different databases besides lemon there are so I can start learning where other data is kept so I ran the following:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
```

I expected to see lemon on the list but I do not, so what is lemon if not a database? What am I seeing on the list following selecting the names of databases? Does every name here have tables that I can pull from?

edit: I forgot to mention lemon is db2, would a db2 database not show up from the above?

Comment: Are you using SSMS?

Comment: that's correct, using 2014

Comment: In the Object Explorer, expand `Server Objects` then `Linked Servers`.

Comment: thanks put this as an answer and ill mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), view the Object Explorer. Then, expand `Server Objects` then `Linked Servers`. It will list all of the linked servers.